# Guvnor rules encoding

Tags: drools, business-rules

I have a Drools decision table in Excel, and some of the strings used in rules have "Á" characters. When I build rules package in Guvnor from this decision table, I get wrong characters in rules source.

For instance,

in spreadsheet -> Área de Lazer|POR,

in built drl file -> �rea de Lazer|POR

Is there any way Guvnor can be tuned to support UTF-8 in this case? Had anyone faced similar issue?

Thanks

---

@Geoffrey De Smet

Hi,

I have added following code to ExcelParser.java:

```
WorkbookSettings ws = new WorkbookSettings();
        ws.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook( inStream , ws);
```

I have successfully built drools project from git-hub, but when I try building guvnor-webapp to test this, either with maven 2.2.1 or maven 3.0.3, I get the same error:

> [ERROR] FATAL ERROR
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Trace
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils
>           at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.AbstractGwtMojo.checkGwtUserVersion(AbstractGwtMojo.java:289)
>           at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.AbstractGwtMojo.getGwtUserJar(AbstractGwtMojo.java:251)
>           at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile(CompileMojo.java:268)
>           at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.doExecute(CompileMojo.java:255)
>           at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute(AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:119)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
>           at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
>           at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
>           at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
>           at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClassDirect(RealmClassLoader.java:195)
>           at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:255)
>           at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:274)
>           at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClass(RealmClassLoader.java:214)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Thank you!

P.S. I have read [README document](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-build-bootstrap), and proceeded as described.

Comment: I've created an issue https://issues.jboss.org/browse/GUVNOR-1250 Could you add in which version you're affected by this?

Comment: Guvnor version: 5.0.0.SNAPSHOT 25673M

Comment: Have you fixed this problem right now?

Comment: @A. Wrinkler - I am working on it. Drools uses JXL to parse CSV and XSL sheets. It is possible to add workbook settings and specify encoding when reading document. See my post below..

Answer (score 2):

[The issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBRULES-2936) is still open and not easy to fix because excel file encoding differs from locale to locale.

One known workaround (suggested by Amer Zec) is to start the app server on which Guvnor runs with `-Djxl.encoding=cp1252` (if you're West-European, otherwise use another encoding than `cp1252`).