# Camel - Drools rules encoding

Tags: excel, ubuntu, character-encoding, apache-camel, drools

I have a Drools decision table in Excel(97/2000 format), and some of the strings used in rules have non-ascii characters like umlauts (Ä). When I build rules package with Camel-Drools integration module in Ubuntu 12.04LTS from this decision table, I get wrong characters in rules source.

For instance,

in spreadsheet -> Ääripää tässä tapauksessa,

in built drl file -> ��rip�� t�ss� tapauksessa

If I use exact same excel files in Windows/Ubuntu/Mac (Eclipse or IDEA makes no difference) development machines or even in Vagrant/VirtualBox/Ubuntu environment, there is no character encoding problems with drools rules.

Code is packaged into Spring-boot Jar-file, which contains Jetty server where application is deplyed. This same JAr file has been used to test in every different environment, but only one failing is the cloud-based testing environment.

Testing Environment is built up with Kitchen & Chef cookbooks and it is a cloud environment, haven't got the foggiest what is the difference between cloud environment and dev envs.

Have tried formatting excel files to UTF-8 encoding, but it seems impossible. And Camel-Drools integration module should have this fixed in their next release (6.0.0 https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBRULES-2936) but that is still in beta and not usable yet. Nor have I got their timetable for stable release.

Anyone got a clue how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you provide an `od -tx1` output of Ääripää tässä tapauksessa from the .drl file?

Comment: I dont have DRL file, it is Excel file that system generates DRL during runtime

Comment: Then how did you obtain the ��rip�� t�ss� tapauksessa?

Comment: I use camel to integrate to drools functionality (which camel-drools module does for me) and then i send input through camel to drools's runtime-generated code which gives me an output after rules have been fired. This result is then provided through REST API to users/frontend. And in the Ubuntu cloud environment, for some reason  encoding doesn't function correctly.

Comment: Like this:
      camelContext.createProducerTemplate().sendBody("direct:accounting1RulesRoute", ImmutableList.of(accountingDto));

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23493398/1627688 has an example of spring configuration for making this kind of camel route

Comment: Decision table sample http://picpaste.com/decisionTable_sample.PNG

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5511532/1627688 provides an workaround but I would really like to know the root cause, since this seems to be system environment related issue

Comment: Here are some environment values if those help with anything:

ubuntu-1204:~$ locale
LANG=fi_FI.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=fi_FI:fi


ubuntu-1204:~$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_GB.utf8
fi_FI.utf8
POSIX‏


‎ubuntu-1204:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)‏


ubuntu-1204:~$ cat /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
fi_FI.UTF-8 UTF-8‏


ubuntu-1204:~$ cat /etc/default/locale
LANG="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="fi_FI:fi"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"

Comment: That's all very well, but who knows how .xsl can be read by the Java interface on this or that system. - Have you tried to use the alternative format, i.e., CSV? This should reduce the issue to the question how text files are interpreted in Java, which depends on the locale, and you can control that.

Comment: Tried CSV format but that rendered file content un-maintainable so the whole purpose of having business rules outside of code and in the hands of business analysts don't work. I'll keep using the workaround until drools releases fix for their bug.

Comment: You can convert back *and* forth between the formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason found!

The cloud environment we use was configured with chef, and somehow the cookbook set character encoding to non-UTF whenever it rebooted cloud instance.

Hence the file was not recognized as UTF, as environment was telling java to use something else.

Thanks for comments and help all!

Answer (score 2):

Use the overloaded methods to specify the `encoding` when telling drools about the XLS:

```
public interface KieResources extends Service {

Resource newUrlResource(URL url);

Resource newUrlResource(URL url,
                        String encoding);

Resource newUrlResource(String path);

Resource newUrlResource(String path,
                        String encoding);

Resource newFileSystemResource(File file);

Resource newFileSystemResource(File file,
                               String encoding);

...

}
```

If you don't do that, it will use the default encoding of the Java platform which uses the default of the operation system (UTF-8 on linux, windows-1252 on a French Windows machine, ...)

Comment: As I'm using drools via Camel integration framework, I don't have control of how KieResources gets called. Camel-drools integration is in 5.6.0 version, which doesnt use KieResources yet, only in version 6+, right?

Comment: drools-camel has been renamed to kie-camel in 6.0 IIRC.

Comment: Great, it has a final release, I'll test with that if it corrects this problem.